# Как узнать какой QCheckBox включен

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollarea, qcheckbox, qbuttongroup

Создал в *Qt Designer* такой шаблон: в `QScrollArea` закинул `QverticalLayout`, а туда добавил один `QCheckBox`. 
Потом в в другом файле все это подключаю и в цикле добавляю другие `checkbox` (их может быть больше 100 шт, пока 10).

Как не используя циклы следить за тем, какие `checkbox` включены и/или после включения/отключения выполнить какое-то действие (планирую сделать фильтр данных). Попробовал поработать с QButtonGroup, но не получилось.

P.S. Буду рад, если ответите еще на пару вопросов:

1. Как можно в шапку `QScrollArea` добавить фильтр, что бы оставались отфильтрованные чекбоксы?
2. Как сделать, так, что бы у `QScrollArea` появилась прокрутка(в некоторых окошках она появляется, а вот в этой нет)?

Основное окно:

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(241, 293)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 181, 221))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 179, 219))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 121, 191))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 241, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Основной файл:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCompleter

import show_notion as sn # это окно из qt 

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, sn.Ui_MainWindow):                           #  +++
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        chbxs = [f'chbx_{i}' for i in range(10)] # названия чекбоксов
        #self.groupVAlignment = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        #self.groupVAlignment.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.groupHAlignmentClicked) 
        for i in chbxs:
            setattr(self, i, QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents))
            getattr(self, i).setText(i[5:])
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(getattr(self, i))
        #self.verticalLayout.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.gg)

        def gg(self):
            print('hello')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Main()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс [**QButtonGroup**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html) предоставляет контейнер для организации групп виджетов-кнопок.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#import show_notion as sn                              # это окно из qt
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(241, 293)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 181, 221))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 179, 219))
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
# ??? 
        ''' 
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 121, 191))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        '''

# -       self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
# +++
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)         
        
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()      #  (self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 241, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CheckBox"))


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        chbxs = [f'chbx_{i}' for i in range(10)]             # названия чекбоксов
        
        #self.groupVAlignment = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        #self.groupVAlignment.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.groupHAlignmentClicked)
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        self.groupVAlignment = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()
        self.groupVAlignment.setExclusive(False)
        self.groupVAlignment.buttonClicked.connect(self.gg)     
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
        for i in chbxs:
            setattr(self, i, QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents))
            getattr(self, i).setText(i[5:])
# +++            
            self.groupVAlignment.addButton(getattr(self, i))            # +++
            
            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(getattr(self, i))
            
        #self.verticalLayout.buttonClicked['int'].connect(self.gg)

    def gg(self, button):
        print(f'hello CheckBox: {button.text()} - {button.isChecked()}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Main()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос.